# Unable to use System.XML.Linq

Tags: xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am working on a project using Mono for Android.  After reading a cross-platform document with Xamarin.  I had my data layer in a separate project and was going to move it to my Mono for Android project and then link those files to my Mono Touch project, and one day perhaps a Windows Phone 8 project.

When I moved the code, I am now unable to compile because of the System.Xml.Linq reference.  The reference shows in the Mono for Android project, but I am unable to use it.  I thought aiming for Froyo may be the problem, but upgrading the project to Gingerbread or Ice Cream Sandwich didn't help.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?  I am a seasoned .NET developer and am well aware of how references work in project, but this one has me stumped.

The project the original code was working on was targeting the Mono/.NET 4 framework

Answer (score 2):

Is your reference to System.Xml.Linq pointing to the .Net version or the Mono version? The one for Mono will have Version 2.0.5.0.

[image: Mono System.Xml.Linq Reference]

Also, is the reference to System.Xml.Linq in a Android Class Library/Application or in a regular .Net Class library. If it is a .Net Class library, I would try referencing the library in your Android application as a compiled (dll) reference and not a project reference. It is not a perfect solution, but I have found that this works when I needed to reference libraries that I use across multiple solutions. The reference will generally work out fine, but if there is anything that is not supported in the Mono version, then it can cause issues.

Assuming you have your code in a class library, your best bet may be to create a Mono specific version of your library project. You can import and use the same class files, but just add some Conditional compilation symbols to have it compile properly for Mono. If you are not familiar with this, take a look at how [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69709) or [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src) manages code for multiple platforms.

Comment: I had the code setup in a separate project file before which targeted the Mono/.NET 4.0 framework.  Can I just move it back to there and forget about it?  Will it cause problems with the Mono for Android version?  The code runs fine on Mono Touch which I was using a link to use the files.  I'm worried that referencing the project will not work now since Mono for Android doesn't even seem to support classes like XDocument.  I've tried adding both the Mono for Android .dll you mentioned and the Mono framework dll and neither seems to work.  Maybe I'll just set the clock back and cross my fingers

Comment: I think you might have something odd going on with your references. Mono for Android supports XDocument and I have used it in a couple of projects without issue.

I might suggest creating a new Mono for Android class library project and adding in your classes to that project. Maybe there is an old reference pointer hanging around. Also, double-check your project references and make sure that they are pointing to the Mono versions as well. The default Mono System.Xml.Linq is at C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll .

Comment: WOW...so I should have added that I was linking those files to a Mono Touch project.  The Mono Touch project didn't have the reference for System.Xml.Linq.  Talk about a rookie mistake.  When I added the reference to the Mono Touch project it compiled fine.  I was being spoofed by the error popping up in the Mono for Android project.  Mike, thank you for helping me through this problem.  When I get a better rep I will upvote.