# How to parse XML With XmlPullParser?

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I read an Xml file with XmlPullParser but it gives Exception (unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @817:4 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4cb5258) when it comes to **Dscp** .

i reader another shot like this before this shot
every thing is ok until this one.
when i remove Dsec  from xml every thing is ok and i read all xml file.
when i  read xml with Dsec i have exception in this shot

The shot before is like this shot

```
<Shot>
        <ShotGUID>59AA1C15D3384B5691FBFB40B0FE38BD</ShotGUID>
        <Title>##Step 2-Categories of Projects</Title>
        <StartTime>00:00:40.00</StartTime>
        <EndTime>00:00:00.00</EndTime>
        <FileName>Shot0042.jpg</FileName>
        <Dscp>Step 2-Categories of Projects

Aggregate project plan identifies four separate categories of projects:

Derivative projects … those that are only incrementally different from existing offerings
Platform projects … major departures from existing offerings … the next generation
Breakthrough projects … involving a newer technology … possibly a “disruptive” technology
R&D projects … “blue sky” or visionary endeavors   

        </Dscp>
<Footer></Footer>

    </Shot>
```

And this is my code :

```
 XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory;
        parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
 ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStreamXmlData = new ByteArrayInputStream(bufferXMLData);
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(byteArrayInputStreamXmlData, "UTF-8");

 List<PageModel> pages = new ArrayList<>();
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        PageModel current = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String eltName = null;

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    eltName = parser.getName();


                    if (eltName.equals("Shot")) {
                        current = new PageModel();
                        pages.add(current);
                    } else if (current != null) {

                        switch (eltName) {
                            case "ShotGUID":
                                current.setShotGUID(parser.nextText());
                                break;

                            case "StartTime": 
                                current.setStartTime(parser.nextText());
                                break;

                            case "EndTime":
                                current.setEndTime(parser.nextText());
                                break;

                            case "FileName":
                                current.setFileName(parser.nextText());
                                break;

                            case "Dscp":
                                current.setDscp(parser.nextText());     

                           case "Footer" :
                                current.setFooter(parser.nextText());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
```

Comment: Is code c#?  Looks like library has bugs.  Try a different library.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924474/unable-to-use-system-xml-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I realized that I couldn't use the **&** character in the Dscp Value and I need to use alternate codes.
What are the special characters in XML?

```
 &lt; (<), &amp; (&), &gt; (>), &quot; ("), and &apos; (').
```